# Excluding words using regex without excluding its variants

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to exclude the word ‘define’ without excluding other forms of the word like ‘defined’ or ‘defining’ but the below mentioned regex doesn’t work. Help.

Regex :

> `^((?!define).)*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundaries around the word `define`:

```
^((?!\bdefine\b).)*$
```

You could also write this pattern as:

```
^(?!.*\bdefine\b).*$
```

### Demo

Comment: There are a few ways you could write your regex, but the general correct answer is to use word boundaries.